# Dictionary Comprehension with a set of Tuple as value

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I have this

```
dict_1 = {1:{("Apple",1),("Orange",1),("Banana",1),("Lemon",1)}}
```

And i would like this :

```
{"Apple","Orange","Banana","Lemon"}
```

What would be the correct comprehension here.

My attempts failed because of

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

means I can not unpack the set.

Comment: `{x for x, y in dict_1[1]}`?

Comment: Thank you and how to deal with multiple keys in a dictionnary

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a single key names `1` in the dict you can simply use

```
dict = {1:{("Apple",1),("Orange",1),("Banana",1),("Lemon",1)}}
{key for key, val in dict[1]} # used the 1 assuming its the only key
```

Output:

```
{"Apple","Orange","Banana","Lemon"}
```

Edit:

Code with any number of variables(keys)

```
dict = {1:{("Apple",1),("Orange",1),("Banana",1),("Lemon",1)},2:{("Apple",1),("Orange",1),("Banana",1),("Lemon",1)}}
resultArray = [{x for x, y in dict[eachkey]} for eachkey in {x for x, y in dict.items()} ]
print(resultArray)
```

Output:

```
[{'Orange', 'Apple', 'Lemon', 'Banana'}, {'Orange', 'Apple', 'Lemon', 'Banana'}]
```

Edit 2:

Code :

```
from itertools import chain
dict = {1:{("Apple",1),("Orange",1),("Banana",1),("Lemon",1)},2:{("Juice",1),("Cocktail",1),("Milk",1),("Soup",1)}}
resultArray = [{x for x, y in dict[eachkey]} for eachkey in {x for x, y in dict.items()} ]
print(set().union(*(resultArray)))
```

Output:

```
{'Lemon', 'Soup', 'Milk', 'Cocktail', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Juice'}
```

Comment: Thank you and you guess my next question, means with more key with the same structure.how to deal with multiple keys?

Comment: How to deal with dict_2 = {1:{("Apple",1),("Orange",1),("Banana",1),("Lemon",1)}, \
   2:{("Juice",1),("Cocktail",1),("Milk",1),("Soup",1)}, \
   3: set(), \
   4:{("Breakfast",1),("Lunch",1),("Dinner",1)} }

Comment: @Easytoday checkout the edit i made to the answer for what you have asked above. Make sure to accept the answer if solved.

Comment: Thank you again, your result is a list of set, is there a mean to just get a set, not a list? I try to replace brackets for curly bracket in your comprrehension and again i got the same error TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'.

Comment: whats ur expected result?, a single set of everything?

Comment: I just expected a set of value, not a list.

Comment: you mean {'Banana', 'Lemon', 'Apple', 'Orange','Banana', 'Lemon', 'Apple', 'Orange'} like this?

Comment: Please post the expected answer so that i can help you on that

Comment: {'Orange', 'Apple', 'Lemon', 'Banana','Lunch', 'Breakfast', 'Dinner', 'Whatever'}

Comment: dict_2 = {1:{("Apple",1),("Orange",1),("Banana",1),("Lemon",1)}, \ 2:{("Juice",1),("Cocktail",1),("Milk",1),("Soup",1)}, \ 3: set(), \ 4:{("Breakfast",1),("Lunch",1),("Dinner",1)} }

Comment: @Easytoday checkout the latest. Make sure to accept and mark the answer as solved if answered.